# How can I get the HTML of an element

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have:

```
<div id="f" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#ddd">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

I want to get `<div id="f" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:#ddd">`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
alert(document.getElementById("f").innerHTML);
alert(document.getElementById("f").outerHTML);
```

and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47yrx/1/) of it.

Comment: Why? You wrote the HTML in the first place so you should know!

Comment: You mean, you want to get **part** of the html of an element. Use outerHTML, and trim the string that immediately follows the first instance of the `>` character.

Comment: @EdHeal it's possible the HTML is dynamic. OP: On your jsFiddle, the second `outerHTML` solution works fine.

Comment: `outerHTML` works fine for me.

Comment: @Ed Heal, There are many elements, I the style is changing, some elements are created using `javascript` and I want to see if the whole is working in the way I am expecting.

Comment: @Ashkan: Wouldn't the debugger built into the browser be a better way of checking that? Right-click the relevant element and choose "Inspect Element" (on any modern browser).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I am actually using `console.log` because sometimes using it make it easier to see what's happening, Only what is important to me is in the output, not lots of other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. However, you could remove the innerHTML content from the outerHTML content.

```
document.getElementById("f").outerHTML.replace(document.getElementById("f").innerHTML,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is to clone it, remove all contents, get `outerHTML`, and then remove the `</div>` from the end.

```
var clone = document.getElementById("f").cloneNode(true);
clone.innerHTML = "";
var html = clone.outerHTML.replace(/<\/div>\s*$/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have the solution, using `outerHTML`. You just want to split the returned string after the first > character, which is easy using JS `.split()`.

For example:

```
var html = document.getElementById("f").outerHTML;
var part = html.split(">")[0] + ">";
```

So: I get the whole HTML, split it by the > character, then add the > back in (because `split()` removes it).

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtOfCode/47yrx/4/) of it.

Comment: It's perfectly valid (and not all that uncommon) for an attribute value to contain a literal `>`, which would break this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0